# How to unit test a synchronous method calling asynchronous method?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, synchronous, async-await

What is the correct way to write a unit test for a synchronous method calling async methods. 
Right now my unit test are passing, but when I try to open the page, it never returns.
Why isn't my unit test failing? How can I make it fail?

I replicated my problem with this simple code:

My passing test:

```
   [TestMethod]
   public void DoSomeWork_WhenWeDoSomeWork_ShouldReturnDone()
   {
      var service = new SyncService();

      const string expected = "Done";
      var actual = service.DoSomeWork();

      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

   }
```

My view that never returns:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var syncService = new SyncService();

        return View((object)syncService.DoSomeWork());
    }
```

My service that never returns to view:

```
    public class SyncService
    {
       public string DoSomeWork()
       {
          return SomeWork().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       }

       private async Task<string> SomeWork()
       {
          var task1 = Task.Delay(1000);
          var task2 = Task.Delay(1000);

          await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

          return "Done";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [don't block on async code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (link to my blog). By blocking on `async` code, you're actually causing a deadlock. This deadlock does not happen in your unit test because [unit tests run in a thread pool context, not an ASP.NET context](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) (link to my blog).

There are [good reasons for *not* having synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). So I recommend getting rid of `DoSomeWork` completely, leaving only `SomeWork` (renamed to `SomeWorkAsync`).

To solve your problem, you should use [asynchronous controller actions](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can help you with this specific example, but I think a good general strategy is to write two tests. One to test if the synchronous method passes the correct data and an other to test if the asynchronous method works properly.

I mostly work in JavaScript and that general approach works for me. Also you can check the documentation of your testing frameworks, maybe it provides some methods for this.

Comment: +1 This is always a good practice. Separate your threading/async logic from any other logic.